# Django, Sentry, Slack: How to capture/display request and response in slack?

Tags: django, logging, slack, sentry

I am using django-1.10 and have configured sentry logger to capture any response status greater than 400.
Sentry is hooked with slack channel.
I am able to get culprit and project information but it does not contains what was the `url`, `request` and `response`.
Want to Log request and response along with culprit and project information.

My Logging config:-
`

```
LOGGING = {
        ....
        'handlers': {
            'sentry': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': ('raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.'
                          'SentryHandler'),
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'sentry_errors': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'handlers': ['sentry'],
                'propagate': False
            },
        }
}
```

`

Code raising sentry alerts:-
`

```
logger = logging.getLogger('sentry_errors')
logger.error("Handled exception occurred", exc_info=True, extra={
                "request": renderer_context['request'].data,
                "response": renderer_context['response'].data
            })
```

`

I am only receiving `Culprit` and `Project` information on slack. Is it possible to capture `request` and `response` on slack?